# bootstrap 4 responsive form containing a two-column section with image

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.6 in a project. I need to display an image in form where:

The image is in one column, and properties of the image (title, etc.) are in a second column.

I want the displayed form to look something like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|                          Title   ..............    |
|                          Caption ..............    |
|                                                    |
|   Image                                            |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my HTML markup for my form:

```
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Form</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>            
        </div>

        <form class="tagForm" id="tag-form" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal-body">

              <div class="form-group">
                
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: inline;">
                      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x350" >
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: inline;">
                      <label class="text-inline"><input type="text" name="photoTitle">Title</label>
                  </div>
                            
              </div>


                <input type="hidden" id="frm-val" name="frm-val" value="">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="status">Option1 </label>
                  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="status">Option2</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="notes">Notes: </label>
                  <input id="notes" class="form-control" type="textarea"/>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input id="form-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I cleanly (and in a responsive way) display the image in one column, and it's properties alongside the image, in another column alongside the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing a BS "row" class.  Anytime you create a div with a "col" class, you'll want to contain those in a "row" class.  Just change

```
<div class="form-group">
```

to

```
<div class="form-group row">
```

If you want the radio buttons and notes in that right col div too, those will need to be contained in the 2nd "col" div.  But I'm not sure that's your end goal based on the mockup.

More grid examples are available on the BS site for v4.6:
[BS v4.6 Grid Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/)

Comment: I'm embarrassed :p  It's been a long day ... Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, do you know why the label **Title** is not displaying inline s specified in the markup? Instead, it is wrapped under the  text input element.